# .htaccess 302 Redirect, Allow all subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So I'd like to standardize the process of updating a site:

1) 302 Redirect all traffic to a subfolder
2) Allow all contents within that subfolder to be viewable (ex, /images, /scripts)
3) IP exception for my IP and others

The following does not work properly... while it redirects all visitors except 1.3.3.7, the "images" directory within the "coming-soon" folder is blocked.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.3.3.7
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/coming-soon/
RewriteRule .* /coming-soon/ [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `/coming-soon/` in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/coming-soon/` only matches the URI `/coming-soon/`, URIs within that directory, such as `/coming-soon/images` or `/coming-soon/files`.

However, if you change the line to this, it should work, because it then would match any URI that begins with `/coming_soon/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming_soon/
```